# how can i call a function that takes an argument in racket?

Tags: math, functional-programming, scheme, computer-science, racket

I am still new in racket language. 
I am implementing a switch case in racket but it is not working.
So, I shift into using the equal and condition. I want to know how can i call a function that takes input. for example: factorial(n) function
I want to call it in :

```
(if (= c 1) (factorial (n))
```

Comment: Your code already calls a function (viz., `=`) of two arguments with two arguments (viz., `c` and `1`).  You didn't wrap `c` and `1` in parentheses, and you shouldn't wrap `n` either.

Answer (score 2):

There are two syntax problems with this snippet:

```
(if (= c 1) (factorial (n)))
```

For starters, an `if` expression in Racket needs three parts:

```
(if <condition> <consequent> <alternative>)
```

The first thing to fix would be to provide an expression that will be executed when `c` equals `1`, and another that will run if `c` is not equal to `1`. Say, something like this:

```
(if (= c 1) 1 (factorial (n)))
```

Now the second problem: in Scheme, when you surround a symbol with parentheses it means that you're trying to execute a function. So if you write `(n)`, the interpreter believes that `n` is a function with no arguments and that you're trying to call it. To fix this, simply remove the `()` around `n`:

```
(if (= c 1) 1 (factorial n))
```

Now that the syntax problems are out of the way, let's examine the logic. In Scheme, we normally use recursion to express solutions, but a recursion has to *advance* at some point, so it will eventually end. If you keep passing the same parameter to the recursion, without modifying it, you'll get caught in an infinite loop. Here's the proper way to write a recursive `factorial` procedure:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (if (<= n 0)                    ; base case: if n <= 0
      1                           ; then return 1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1))))) ; otherwise multiply and advance recursion
```

Notice how we decrement `n` at each step, to make sure that it will eventually reach zero, ending the recursion. Once you get comfortable with this solution, we can think of making it better. Read about [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), see how the compiler will optimize our loops as long as we write them in such a way that the last thing done on each execution path is the recursive call, with nothing left to do after it. For instance, the previous code can be written more efficiently as follows, and see how we pass the accumulated answer in a parameter:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (let loop ([n n] [acc 1])
    (if (<= n 0)
        acc
        (loop (- n 1) (* n acc)))))
```

**UPDATE**

After taking a look at the comments, I see that you want to implement a `switchcase` procedure. Once again, there are problems with the way you're declaring functions. This is wrong:

```
(define fact(x)
```

The correct way is this:

```
(define (fact x)
```

And for actually implementing `switchcase`, it's possible to use nested `if`s as you attempted, but that's not the best way. Learn how to use the [`cond`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) expression or the [`case`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html) expression, either one will make your solution simpler. And anyway you have to provide an additional condition, in case `c` is neither `1` nor `2`. Also, you're confounding the parameter name - is it `c` or `x`? With all the recommendations in place, here's how your code should look:

```
(define (switchcase c)
  (cond ((= c 1) (fact c))
        ((= c 2) (triple c))
        (else (error "unknown value" c))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In racket-lang, conditionals with `if` has syntax:

```
(if <expr> <expr> <expr>)
```

So in your case, you have to provide another `<expr>`.

```
(define (factorial n)
  (if (= n 1)     1     (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
      ;^exp       ^exp  ^exp        
(factorial 3)
```

The results would be 6

**Update:**

```
(define (factorial n)
  (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))

(define (triple x)
  (* 3 x))

(define (switchcase c)
  (if (= c 1) 
    (factorial c)
    (if(= c 2)
      (triple c) "c is not 1 or 2")))

(switchcase 2)
```

Comment: thank you but iddnt mean it that way .. what i meant is the following:
(define fact(x) (if ( <= x 0) 1 (* x (fact(- x 1 ))))))
(define Triple(x) (* 3 x)) 
 now i have 2 fxns and i want to use a switch case which ddnt work either so i used the condition. but it is still giving me error on the function call part? 
(define (switchcase c)
(if (= c 1) (fact(x)))
(if(= c 2) (triple(x))))
If you could help me use it with input and switch case like in c++ that would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: @user3080673 You should just forget about trying to write C++ in Racket. Madness lies that way. You're learning a different language, not a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something a lot closer to a switch case  given you can return procedures.

```
(define (switch input cases)
 (let ((lookup (assoc input cases)))
    (if lookup
        (cdr lookup)
        (error "Undefined case on " input " in " cases))))

(define (this-switch c)
 (let ((cases (list (cons 1 triple)
                    (cons 2 factorial))))
   ((switch c cases) c)))
```